# java.io.FileNotFoundException: Caused by Reading + Writing

Tags: xml, dom, file-io

I'm trying to read of a XML file and rewrtie it:

```
try {

        DocumentBuilderFactory docFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder docBuilder = docFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
         FileInputStream inputstream = new FileInputStream(dat3);  
        Document doc = docBuilder.parse(inputstream);

        TransformerFactory transformerFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
        Transformer transformer = transformerFactory.newTransformer();
        transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.INDENT, "yes");
        DOMSource source = new DOMSource(doc);
        StreamResult result = new StreamResult(new File(dat3).getAbsolutePath());
        transformer.transform(source, result);

       } catch (ParserConfigurationException pce) {
        pce.printStackTrace();
       } catch (TransformerException tfe) {
        tfe.printStackTrace();
       } catch (IOException ioe) {
        ioe.printStackTrace();
       } catch (SAXException sae) {
        sae.printStackTrace();
       }
```

But its seems not to work because i think there is a conflict in writing and reading so:

transformer.transform(source, result);
Drops the result  java.io.FileNotFoundException: Access denied

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code works ok. I try it with this sample.

```
public class Tester {

private static String dat3 = "data/xml";

public static void main(String[] args) {

    try {

        DocumentBuilderFactory docFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory
                .newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder docBuilder = docFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
        FileInputStream inputstream = new FileInputStream(dat3);
        Document doc = docBuilder.parse(inputstream);

        TransformerFactory transformerFactory = TransformerFactory
                .newInstance();
        Transformer transformer = transformerFactory.newTransformer();
        transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.INDENT, "yes");
        DOMSource source = new DOMSource(doc);
        StreamResult result = new StreamResult(
                new File(dat3).getAbsolutePath());
        transformer.transform(source, result);

    } catch (ParserConfigurationException pce) {
        pce.printStackTrace();
    } catch (TransformerException tfe) {
        tfe.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException ioe) {
        ioe.printStackTrace();
    } catch (SAXException sae) {
        sae.printStackTrace();
    }

}

}
```

Review dat3 file permissions.

Comment: Why should that work? it didnt i only usess input stream for a special char path

Comment: File dat3 is catched by FileInputStream and it's not accesible if you don't close first. I can not test right now but I think it will work.

Comment: im getting a readerror, if i completly remove the FileInputstream like "Document doc = docBuilder.parse(dat3);" it also doesnt work and drops  the access denied error

Comment: I update my answer. I try it on eclipse and your code work ok. Maybe you don't have write permissions on file.

Comment: Windows 7, If I remove the read-only hook of the XML it works. But is this the only conlcusion because of the hook in read-only?

Comment: You need write permission for update xml content of the file.